# BS 4 find elements in element

Tags: python, web

I would want to find some elements of a website, but only that elements which are in some element. Then I want to add them to an array. I make this simple code but something is not working:

```
beautiful_soup.find_all(element, {'class': 'some-class'})
```

Nothing happening, but I'm sure this works. Generally I'm finding all `elements` with `some-class` and then I want to find in this elements other elements with other class. I want to do that, because if I'm not doing this and adding it to array I got to elements which are "sons" of different elements. Of course I make all boring code with setting up bs4 and I checked, bs4 is working.

Website: Amazon (search tab)
Excepted Output: Product + price

E.g:

track('macbook')

Excepted output: [['Macbook pro', 990], [...]]

---

Thanks for any help

PS. Sorry for my english, I know that's pretty bad specially in "technology" describe.

Comment: so please provide the code, url of website and expected output - That would help to answer your question

Comment: Ok, website is just amazon and excepted output is name of a product and price of it.
@HedgeHog

Comment: Not what would be expected - No concret url, no code? -> [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple example**
Based on some sparse information...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
data = """
    <div data-asin="B0863ZJ1T3" data-index="1" data-uuid="47d184c2-ea2c-4758-95ce-d34d2ed6dc71" data-component-type="s-search-result" class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28" data-component-id="8" data-cel-widget="search_result_1">
        <span class="a-price-whole">999,00</span>
        <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal" dir="auto">Apple MacBook Air (13", 1,1&nbsp;GHz dual-core Intel Core&nbsp;i3 Prozessor der 10.&nbsp;Generation, 8&nbsp;GB RAM, 256 GB) - Gold (Vorgängermodell)</span>
    </div>
    <div data-asin="B081FZHSLZ" data-index="2" data-uuid="2c44727b-46a2-45d0-b06a-e95f4bec3bd9" data-component-type="s-search-result" class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item s-asin sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28" data-component-id="12" data-cel-widget="search_result_2">
        <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal" dir="auto">Neues Apple MacBook Pro (16", 16GB RAM, 512GB Speicherplatz, 2,6GHz Intel&nbsp;Core&nbsp;i7) - Silber</span>
        <span class="a-price-whole">2.287,23</span>
    </div>
"""
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    
elements = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-component-type':'s-search-result'})
    
for element in elements:
    title = element.find('span', class_='a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal').getText()
    price = element.find('span', class_='a-price-whole').getText()
    print(title, price)
```

**Output**

```
Apple MacBook Air (13", 1,1 GHz dual-core Intel Core i3 Prozessor der 10. Generation, 8 GB RAM, 256 GB) - Gold (Vorgängermodell) 999,00
Neues Apple MacBook Pro (16", 16GB RAM, 512GB Speicherplatz, 2,6GHz Intel Core i7) - Silber 2.287,23
```